# Returning Related Fields with acts_as_xlsx ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Having installed the gem `acts_as_xlsx` I can't see how to return the related field accross active record.

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_xlsx  :columns => [:customer_name ]
  attr_accessible :customer_id, :account_id, :first_weight, :ticket_no, :second_weight, :net_weight, :product_id, :vehicle_id, :customer_name, :vehicle_reg, :product_details, :weight


  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :vehicle
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :account
```

when producing the file by tickets.xlsr i get the result of the cutomer_id i.e 30 not the customer name how to I return the name instead?

Controller

```
def report
    @q = @gaurd.ticket.where("net_weight > 0").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).search(params[:q])
    @ticket = @q.result(distinct: true)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xlsx {
      xlsx_package = @ticket.to_xlsx
      begin 
        temp = Tempfile.new("report.xlsx") 
        xlsx_package.serialize temp.path
        send_data xlsx_package.to_stream.read, :filename => 'tickets.xlsx', :type=> "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        ensure
        temp.close 
        temp.unlink
      end
      }
    end
  end
```

I have spent most of the day trying but cannot get it to download any more than the field data such as customer_id rather than the related `ticket.customer.name`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a excellent railscasts to export XLS http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

What to do.
in  **config/application.rb**

`require 'csv'`

**in the view**

`<%= link_to "Excel", model_path(format: "xls") %>`

**model_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @products = Product.order(:name)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @products.to_csv }
    format.xls # { send_data @products.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
  end
end
```

**models/model.rb**

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    all.each do |product|
      csv << model.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

THIS IS REALLY IMPORTANT

**config/initializers/mime_types.rb**

`Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls`

**views/models/index.xls.erb**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Release Date</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Price</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% @models.each do |model| %>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= model.id %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= model.name %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= model.released_on %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= model.price %></Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

With this you should have no problem exporting to XLS files

Comment: This method does not work well with Office 2010 as it will say that file is corrupt, and warn the users each time they open the file.  Also, if a field contains a -0 (rounding), then it will say that data has been lost.  I'm in the middle of converting all my .xls reports done in the manner posted above to .xlsx reports.

Comment: Yes, Even I faced the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The trick that I have found to show fields from other tables is to specify the columns and then for the column name you use :'external_table:field_name', for example:

```
send_data xlsx_package.to_stream.read, :filename => 'tickets.xlsx', 
  :type => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
  :columns => [:id, :'customer.name', :account_id]
```

If customer is only sometimes available then the report will fail.  An alternative to this problem is to create a method that references customer.name and returns a value such as "No customer" in the case of a non-existent customer relationship.

Alternatively, you can generate the xlsx file on the fly and specify additional logic.  See the documentation for details.